# Click even doesn't work on dynamically generated elements

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, themes

1 – I have a search and filter form on my mobile site (480px and below) made with Search and Filter Pro plugin. Here’s the screenshot showing what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Z3E.jpg
If you click on “Pokaż filtry” filters will appear. The problem is that when you expand it and just click “filtruj” (filter), the “Pokaż filtry” button will stop working – you can click as many times as you want but it won’t expand anymore (it becomes unclickable). Everything will start working again after refresh.

Second problem is very similar to the first one. At 480px and below, when you choose any option and click “filtruj” the whole search form will dissapear. Everything will start working fine again after refresh.

At resolution 960px to 480px there’s a button to show sidebar - https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTm4e.jpg . There’s also a Search and Filter form. When you use it, you can’t close the sidebar – the button just stops working (becomes unclickable).

These issues are 100% caused by Search and Filter Pro plugin. When I deactivate it, everything works fine. The issue is most likely related to this: [Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements/29674985#29674985) but unfortunately I have no idea what to do with it.

Here's my site - http://gromocje.pl/

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it? I feel like I tried everything... I've never seen such a issue.

I tried to use this code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.otfm-sp__title', function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('js-otfm-sp__opened js-otfm-sp__closed');
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('js-otfm-sp__opened')) {
            $(this).parent().attr('aria-expanded', 'true')
        } else {
            $(this).parent().attr('aria-expanded', 'false')
        }
    });
```

but no luck :/

Comment: Have you asked on the Search and Filter Pro web site? As a paid product they should give you some support.

Comment: Yeah, but they don't seem to know the answer and it takes very long to get any. I'm a bit in hurry to solve this, that's why I'm asking here